# I want to delete my own cross-posted question but I don't know how

Tags: support, cross-posting, self-delete

I cross-posted the same question on Stack Overflow and Statistics Stack Exchange not knowing it's not allowed.

I want to delete one of them but I don't know how to do it. What should I do?  Can I delete my own question?  If it's possible how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `delete` link at the bottom of your question, just near `share`, `edit` and `flag`.

Comment: thank you so much . is this link delete my question immediately or is this just a vote to delete the question and will delete it later ?

Comment: I never deleted one of my questions, but it looks like *you* are going to do it soon! Keep us informed.

Comment: yes I want to delete it immediately . I choose that link and a frame opened which said `vote to delete` . I think this link will gain delete votes . but anyway thank you so much for your guidance . whether it will be deleted immediately or be deleted soon ; my problem is solved .

Comment: I checked it again this link will delete your own question immediately . my question is deleted now . thanks to you `@Stéphane Bruckert`

Comment: hi, your answer could be more complete, for example if it included what happen when you can't delete your question via this link, etc

Comment: guys I think this link won't delete the closed questions . It just delete open ones .

Comment: @BaharehLV As the post author, your delete vote is binding, and thus results in immediate deletion - if you have the right to delete the post. You don't have the right to delete questions that have an upvoted answer, you don't have the right to delete an answer of yours if it is accepted. I'm not sure, but I think you can only delete a closed question after two days.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer thank you so much . I think you are right . so I should try to delete closed questions after 2 days .